# Bogus RuleFor private field

Tags: c#, unit-testing, bogus

I have class with private readonly field

```cs
        public class Bar
        {
            private readonly ICollection<Foo> somePrivateCollection = new HashSet<Foo>();
            public IEnumerable<Foo> SomePublicCollection => somePrivateCollection;

            public int z;
        }
```

And

```cs
        public class Foo
        {
            public int x;
        }
```

I can set this field by GetField => SetValue

```cs
        [Fact]
        public void someTest()
        {
            var fooObjects = new Faker<Foo>().Generate(1);
            var barObject = new Faker<Bar>().RuleFor(t => t.z, f => f.Random.Int())
                                            .Generate();

            barObject.GetType()
                     .GetField("somePrivateCollection", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                                                        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance)
                     .SetValue(barObject, fooObjects);
        }
```

But how can I set this field using same style

```cs
            var barObject = new Faker<Bar>().RuleFor(t => t.z, f => f.Random.Int())
                                            .RuleSetter("somePrivateCollection",fooObjects)
                                            .Generate();
```

Comment: Why does `somePrivateCollection` need to be updated directly?  Also, why create a fake of a concrete class?

Comment: @AndrewS for testing purpose, testing function that add items to list using same function, i think it's not good idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if difference between public and private field just in 1 letter

```cs
 public class PrivateBinder : Binder
    {
        public override Dictionary<string, MemberInfo> GetMembers(Type t)
        {
            var members = base.GetMembers(t);

            var privateBindingFlags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
            var allPrivateMembers = t.GetMembers(privateBindingFlags)
                                     .OfType<FieldInfo>()
                                     .Where( fi => fi.IsPrivate )
                                     .Where( fi => !fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CompilerGeneratedAttribute)).Any() )
                                     .ToArray();

            foreach( var privateField in allPrivateMembers ){
                members.Add(privateField.Name, privateField);
            }
            return members;
        }
    }

public class DataFaker<T> : Faker<T> where T : class
    {
        public DataFaker(IBinder backingFieldBinder): base(binder: backingFieldBinder)
        {
        }

        public DataFaker<T> UsingPrivate()
        {
            return base.CustomInstantiator(f => Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), nonPublic: true) as T)
                    as DataFaker<T>;
        }

        public virtual Faker<T> RuleForPrivate<TProperty>(Expression<Func<T, TProperty>> property, TProperty value)
        {
            var propName = PropertyName.For(property);
            propName = propName.First()
                               .ToString()
                               .ToLower() +
                    propName.Substring(1);
            return AddRule(propName, (f, t) => value);
        }
    }

 var data =new DataFaker<Bar>(backingFieldBinder).UsingPrivate().RuleForPrivate(x => x.SomeCollection, value)
```